# Show preloading page only once with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, preload

I am building a website that has a loading page which shows a short load bar animation while the page loads. However, I discovered that this is played whenever that HTML page is clicked. I want to show the loading animation only when a person first enters a page and when they refresh the page! 
Can I set a jquery attribute to play the loading animation only once?

This is my code so far.

jQuery

```
var width = 100,
  perfData = window.performance.timing,
  EstimatedTime = -(perfData.loadEventEnd - perfData.navigationStart),
  time = parseInt((EstimatedTime/1000)%60)*100;

// Loadbar Animation
$(".loadbar").function() {
  $(this).animate({
    width: width + "%"
  }, time);

  setTimeout(function () {
    $('.preloaderWrap').fadeOut(300);
  }, time);

});
```

HTML

```
<section class="preloaderWrap">
    <div class="percentage"></div>
    <div class="loader">
      <div class="trackbar">
        <div class="loadbar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="glow"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.preloaderWrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #000081;
  z-index : 200;
}
.loader,.percentage{
  height: 3px;
  max-width: 200px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin : auto;
}
.trackbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #525252;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.99;
}
.loadbar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [LocalStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) were it will set for first load and then it will skip
Code :

```
// Loadbar Animation
    var storage = window.localStorage; //set localstorage object in storage var
if(storage.getItem("loading_bar_flag") == 1){
 $('.preloaderWrap').hide();


}else{


  $(".loadbar").animate({
    width: width + "%"
  }, time);

  setTimeout(function () {
    $('.preloaderWrap').fadeOut(300);
  }, time);


   storage.setItem("loading_bar_flag",1);
 }
```

Comment: an error occurs from }); storage.setItem("loading_bar_flag",1);}